# How to set separate log file to log 400 errors in nginx

Tags: nginx, error-logging

I have a django application hosted using nginx. I need to log all the 400 errors from my web page separately in nginx.

The docs I found was the configuration to give separate response error page for 400 errors, but its not logging the errors.

```
server {                                  
listen 443 ssl;      
server_name world.dev;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/world.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/world.key;

error_log /home/ubuntu/pro/world/error_world.log;
access_log /home/ubuntu/pro/world/access.log;

error_page 400  /400.html;
location  /400.html       
{  internal;             
   error_log /400.log error;  //not logging the errors       
}

 location / {
    uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/worlduwsgi.sock;
    include uwsgi_params;
           }
}
```

Comment: Alexey Ten : i've posted the full code above..

Comment: I don't see any `root` directive. Do you have `400.html` page?

Comment: ya..i'm getting the error page. But its not logging any errors.